# Remove parameters form URL via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried to change

```
http://localhost/archives?key=[uncicode string]
```

to

```
http://localhost/archives/[uncicode string]
```

For example

```
http://localhost/archives?key=سلdf
```

to

```
http://localhost/archives/سلdf
```

How can I do it?

```
RewriteRule ^archives\/([.*]+)$ archives?key=$1
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+archives\?key=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /archives/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^archives/([^/]+)/?$ /archives?key=$1 [L,B,NE,QSA]
```

Comment: You need to enter: `localhost/archives/test` in your browser not the other way round

Comment: indeed I want to enter localhost/archives?key=test  in my browser and it be change to localhost/archives/test